# I'm trying to get over masturbation

Tags: masturbation

I'm a 14 year old boy and I've been trying to get on the path of Allah for the past months.

I've been sinful, masturbating and watching pornography, which I know was haram but I still kept doing it, but I'm trying to get away from it these days by praying everyday, it's very hard for me and I feel like I've been addicted to masturbation, but I'm making progress because this issue was occurring to me every day, now it occurs every 3-4 days and I know it's very sinful to do anything like this but please I need guidance, I want to try to stray off of this najasa permanently, I've tried to get my mind off of it by praying and honestly, I don't know if I should let my parents know about any of this.

I'm in need of guidance, and I need something that can work guaranteed, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With availability of things online , people sometimes falls on these sinful act.
**Solutions:**

1. Fasting shows results.
2. Avoiding thoughts are hard but you can with practice replace them with some future productive/imaginative ideas.
3. Avoiding such contents is hard but you can replace them.
4. Informing your guardians is totally upto you but it's something you brothers may already faced , so you can discuss with them.
5. Find your companion for life, getting NikKahfied is not really that hard.

Answer (score 1):

Ask Allah to not let you relapse.
Protect you ears and seeing (lower you gaze) and try to control your thoughts.
For your ears: find things to listen to: Quran, tafsir, dhikr, islamic talks... Or other productive things.
Try to fast (even for half-day, then slowly try for one day), fast the three white days of the month.
Got to the mosque, pray, read the Quran and make dua, seclude yourself there for some period
See the company of good people.
Lower your gaze.
Fasting (the best solution for me) helps reduce impulses, libido.
Keep yourself busy with productive work, exercise, do a group sport.

If you relapse anyway.

Tell Allah that you did really wanted to do but the desires were a bit too high. Beg him to lower the desires and on your side make a firmer (by building upon the guilt feeling) resolution to not relapse. Tie your camel by re-implementing the above.

Slowly surely you will get out.

Answer (score 0):

Salam alaikum Habibi,

do you have the control over your body or is your Nafs controlling? You are a strong man and Allah loves you to be a rightous man. He gives you health and protects you.

Be thankful to him and whenever a Sexual thought crosses your mind, imagine that you die in this state while watching a pornography. We all dont know when the Angel of death visits us. Thats why we need to be prepared for this moment at every time. May Allah blesses ypu with a rightous wife in the future.

Comment: I do not know if I'm controlling myself but I am trying to, ever since I discovered this entire problem of pornography, I've been addicted ever since, but now I'm trying to stray away off of it.
But thank you for the advice, I will try applying it.

Answer (score 0):

And those who guard their private parts Except from their wives or those their right hands possess, for indeed, they are not to be blamed -But whoever seeks beyond that, then they are the transgressors - (70:29-31)(saheeh international) It is clear mastrubation is haram and who does thos has sin ans should repent to allah for He accepts repentence and forgive his servant. Hadith

حَدَّثَنَا عُمَرُ بْنُ حَفْصِ بْنِ غِيَاثٍ، حَدَّثَنَا أَبِي، حَدَّثَنَا الأَعْمَشُ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي عُمَارَةُ، عَنْ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ يَزِيدَ، قَالَ دَخَلْتُ مَعَ عَلْقَمَةَ وَالأَسْوَدِ عَلَى عَبْدِ اللَّهِ فَقَالَ عَبْدُ اللَّهِ كُنَّا مَعَ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم شَبَابًا لاَ نَجِدُ شَيْئًا فَقَالَ لَنَا رَسُولُ اللَّهُ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏

‏ يَا مَعْشَرَ الشَّبَابِ مَنِ اسْتَطَاعَ الْبَاءَةَ فَلْيَتَزَوَّجْ، فَإِنَّهُ أَغَضُّ لِلْبَصَرِ، وَأَحْصَنُ لِلْفَرْجِ، وَمَنْ لَمْ يَسْتَطِعْ فَعَلَيْهِ بِالصَّوْمِ، فَإِنَّهُ لَهُ وِجَاءٌ ‏"

‏‏‏

Narrated `Abdullah:

We were with the Prophet (ﷺ) while we were young and had no wealth whatever. So Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "O young people! Whoever among you can marry, should marry, because it helps him lower his gaze and guard his modesty (i.e. his private parts from committing illegal sexual intercourse etc.), and whoever is not able to marry, should fast, as fasting diminishes his sexual power."

Sahih al-Bukhari 5066 In-book : Book 67, Hadith 4 USC-MSA web (English) : Vol. 7, Book 62, Hadith 4  (deprecated) Sahih Bukhari

وعن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏

‏كُتب على ابن آدم نصيبه من الزنا مدرك ذلك لا محالة‏:‏ العينان زناهما النظر، والأذنان زناهما الاستماع، واللسان زناه الكلام، واليد زناها البطش، والرجل زناها الخطا، والقلب يهوى ويتمنى، ويصدق ذلك الفرج أو يكذبه‏"

‏‏‏ ‏(‏‏(‏متفق عليه‏‏ وهذا لفظ مسلم، ورواية البخاري مختصرة‏)‏‏)‏‏‏

Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) said:

The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Allah has written the very portion of Zina which a man will indulge in. There will be no escape from it. The Zina of the eye is the (lustful) look, the Zina of the ears is the listening (to voluptuous songs or talk), the Zina of the tongue is (the licentious) speech, the Zina of the hand is the (lustful) grip, the Zina of the feet is the walking (to the place where he intends to commit Zina), the heart yearns and desires and the private parts approve all that or disapprove it."

[Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

This is the wording in Muslim; Al-Bukhari wording is a bit short.

Sunnah.com : Book 18, Hadith 112 Arabic/English book : Book 18, Hadith 1622 Riyad us Saliheen

Indulge in dhikr . there are many differnt dhikrs e.g for evening and morning which will rise our level in paradise.if u cant find some dhikr content then tell me
Have controal over yourself and btw i am too 14 year old xd

Comment: I recommend fasting. It's an excellent solution.